# How to Ensure 2 columns are created by default for every table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am in the process of designing an application for my company. We will be using SQL Server as the Database for the application. I may not be involved when the actual tables are being created in the database.

However, I want to ensure that 2 columns (viz., creationdate, modifydate) are present in each table that is created by the developer. Also I want to restric the developer in using the Identity Columns, since my management has asked me to do so without assigning any specific reason except that they want the data to be generated only through the application even if it is a running serial number.

I am not sure on how to achieve this, without getting involved in the actual creation of the tables.

Kindly guide me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use DDL trigger and catch the events which fire after a table is created

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR create_table
AS   
select eventdata()--this is sample,here you need to parse event data
```

Now creating a table will ensure,you have access to below xml

```
<UserName>dbo</UserName>
<DatabaseName>PerformanceV3</DatabaseName>
<SchemaName>dbo</SchemaName>
<ObjectName>test111</ObjectName>
<ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType>
<TSQLCommand>
<SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
<CommandText>create table dbo.test111
(
id int
)
</CommandText>
</TSQLCommand>
```

You can parse above xml and check for required columns  and can rollback or do whatever you need

---below is psuedo code on how you can do this

```
Alter TRIGGER safety   
ON DATABASE   
FOR create_table
AS   
Begin
Declare @EventData XML 
set @eventdata= EVENTDATA();

declare @tsqlcmd varchar(max)

Set @tsqlcmd= @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

if  @tsqlcmd  not like '%columns you need%'
begin
print 'add those two columns'
rollback
end
end
```

Comment: Might be worth including alter table statements too.

Comment: @GarethLyons:added now

Comment: @ZoharPeled:not totally sure on what does your statement meant

Comment: You create a DDL trigger for create table, right? You can know in the trigger what table was created and if it has the columns you want, if it doesn't have them, you can simply create a dynamic alter table statement to add them to the table that fired the trigger....

Comment: @TheGameiswar What if  need 2 columns with different data types. Example one is varchar and other is date time.

Comment: Different datatypes doesn't matter.you can construct based on above example

Answer (score 0):

You can query for existing tables that don't match the criteria via this:

```
SELECT 
    SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS [Schema], 
    o.name AS [Table], o.object_id, o.create_date, o.modify_date
FROM 
    sys.objects o
WHERE 
    o.type = 'U'
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND ((NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                      FROM sys.columns c 
                      INNER JOIN sys.types t on t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id 
                      WHERE c.object_id = o.object_id 
                        AND c.name = 'modifydate' 
                        AND t.name IN ('date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'smalldatetime'))
          AND 
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                      FROM sys.columns c 
                      INNER JOIN sys.types t on t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id 
                      WHERE c.object_id = o.object_id 
                        AND c.name = 'creationdate' 
                        AND t.name IN ('date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'smalldatetime'))
        )
        OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = o.object_id AND c.is_identity = 1)
    )
ORDER BY 
    SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id), o.name
```

Comment: This query is going to check for existence of the columns after the creation of the tables if understood correctly. I wanted to restrict the creation of the table if it does not have the specified columns like **CreatedOn** (datetime) and **CreatedBy** (int).

Comment: Yep, but it gives you a fall back to check in case anything's been missed.